# What is the difference between Shopify checkout liquid template page:load event and DOMContentLoaded?

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-template

Shopify checkout liquid offers an event called:

```
page:load
```

[Documentation: page-load](https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/layouts/checkout-liquid#page-load)

Unfortunately, the documentation is sparse.
What is the difference between page:load and regular JavaScript DOMContentLoaded event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MDN webdocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

> The DOMContentLoaded event fires when the initial HTML document has
> been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets,
> images, and subframes to finish loading.

While from [Shopify Docs](https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/layouts/checkout-liquid#page-events)

> All of the checkout steps are hosted at a single URL path, where the
> content is loaded dynamically depending on the current step.

Shopify is most probably loading some stuff on their end on **DOMContentLoaded** and fires **page:load** event when everything is ready and you can make your DOM customizations. Moreover, **DOMContentLoaded** will only be fired once for whole checkout, but **page:load** would be fired once for each Checkout step.

Same thing has been described in the docs for **page:load**.

> The page:load event is triggered when the content of each step is
> loaded. This is the default event that you should use when adding
> content into the page on load.